# Does Samadhi mean that the soul never gets reincarnated?

Tags: consciousness

It is said that the cycle of birth and detach continues until one's mind merges with infinite consciousness. Does it mean that once the mind merges with infinite consciousness (samadhi), it doesn't get associated with other body. So, the mind/soul of great people like Vivekananda will never reappear, because they all attained Samadhi.?

Comment: That's what is called Moksha where ATMA need not be born again!

Comment: Does that mean that the atma lives on (somewhere) but it doesn't get reincarnated in the form of a human being?

Comment: Yes Atma lives in Vaikuntha, Kailash,Goloka etc.. or it completely becomes absorbed in Parabrahman! Because Atma is not some separate living entity. Brahman's swaroopa is the Purush, or atma (ref Bhagavad Gita). ATMA is non different from Paramatma like creator isnt separate from creation.